# Initialize a Mongodb on server

Tags: mongodb

I want to use a script to initialise a MongoDB on a production server from my mongodb developpement instance.

I tried this method on local and it works 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

@jeorfevre you told me about the import, Can you please give me a small exemple with the import, I found something you talk about this? docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

once you have your database dev database ready to be installed in production.

1. Launch a command line
2. run mongodump

> mongodump --host mongodb.example.net --port 27017 --out /path/backup/

3. transfert the exported file to the server (this depends on server envs)
4. run mongorestore on the server

> mongorestore --port 27017 /path/backup/